# ASP.Net MVC Routing: How to catch the root of a website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my global.asax I have three routes:

```
//MemberHome is supposed to handle urls like http://localhost/johndoe
routes.MapRoute(
   "MemberHome", // Route name                
   "{username}", 
   new { controller = "PublicMember", action = "Index", username = "username" }
);

//Home is supposed to catch http://localhost/  
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",           
    ""
);

// the default way of doing things..    
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

The problem is, I can get them to work separtely (just home or just MemberHome)
But when they are both activated its either Home or MemberHome which gives me a 404 resource not found..

Any idea how I can get this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the first part of the route to something distinct. Eg:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "MemberHome", // Route name                
   "MemberHome/{username}", 
   new { controller = "PublicMember", action = "Index", username = "username" }
);
```

or:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "Home/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

That way they will be distinct. Whichever one is given the fixed part of the route should come first, as otherwise the route handler will match the wildcard one first...